# Save an image or several files what my telegram bot gets, to a specific directory

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot

```
@self.__bot.message_handler(content_types=['photo'])
def on_photo(message):
  file_id = message.photo[-1].file_id
  file_info = self.__bot.get_file(file_id)
```

I created a bot in the telegram and one of the commands is to send a picture to create a post from it.
I want the image you send to it to be saved in the folder of my choice ...
How do you do that?
I use telebot in python I would love to help

Comment: I don't understand where is the problem? And where is your code?

Comment: the problem is that i don't know how to download this photo (in the code above) to specifically directory...

Comment: on [telebot](https://github.com/KyleJamesWalker/telebot) page I found `Currently a work in progress, doesn't do much now` and it seems telebot don't have special function to download it so you have to use directly API like in answer below. In other bots you may have special function for this. ie. `python-telegram-bot` has [download](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.file.html#telegram.File.download)

Answer (score 2):

```
@self.__bot.message_handler(content_types=['photo'])
def on_photo(message):
  file_id = message.photo[-1].file_id
  file_info = self.__bot.get_file(file_id)
  file = requests.get('https://api.telegram.org/file/bot{0}/{1}'.format(API_TOKEN, file_info.file_path))
  with open('photo.jpg','wb') as f:
    f.write(file.content)
```